# I am getting an AssertionError while trying to create a Virtualenv using Python on Windows10

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am a Python beginner/Noob and have very limited knowledge of Python and it's setup bar the very small amount of videos I have seen.

I am currently in the process of learning python and am now needing to use virtual environments.

I have to tried to get find an answer online related to my issue but am getting nowhere.

My issue is that I am getting an Assertionerror while creating a Virtualenv using cmd in Windows 10.

I go into my projects directory to have a look at the created folder (of Virtualenv which is getting made) and inside it only contains one other folder named lib which is empty. I cannot seem to active this virtualenv as it seems incomplete and I don't know whats causing this. It looks to me that there are issued in copying over the required files from the main python directory.

Could this issue be related to where Python or my projects have been saved or a directory issue of some sort?

Here is the CMD runscript:

```
C:\Users\Jamie\PycharmProjects>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'd:'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "d:\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "D:\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 870, in main
symlink=options.symlink,
File "D:\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1156, in create_environment
install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, 
site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear,
symlink=symlink)
File "D:\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1445, in install_python
copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
File "D:\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1335, in 
copy_required_modules
dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
File "D:\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1264, in change_prefix
assert relative_path[0] == os.sep
AssertionError
```

Would appreciate any help with this.

regards

Comment: You can delete the extra spaces manually.

Comment: Thanks, have just amended it, should be clearer to read now :)

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: Not saying it's the cause, but 'venv' is a builtin module in python3; recommend using a different name for your virtual environment. (And if you are using python3 already, might as well use `python3 -m venv SomeName` rather than virtualenv.)

Comment: I am using python 3.5.3 which I believe to be the latest version. I have also tried creating environments with a few different names and all of them have the same issue. The file does get made in my projects folder but it only contains an empty LIB folder inside and nothing else.

Comment: I've solved the issue folks. I just uninstalled python and reinstalled it again and it fixed my issue :D